# tab through just labels instead of circles in radio buttons html

Tags: html, angularjs, forms, radio-button

I want to hide the radio button circles and just tab through the labels. I was able to hide the circle but when i use tab key to navigate through all the labels, it does not focus on the respective label. The picture below demonstrates the label that i want to navigate through and select any one.

[image]

Currently i use radio buttons and am trying to navigate. The navigation using keyboard is working but it does not focus on the label thats selected.

```
div
                label.font-normal(ng-repeat="priority in vm.priorities")
                    input(type="radio", ng-value="priority", ng-model="vm.selectedPriority", name="priority.{{ priority }}", ng-change="vm.changedPriority()")
                    span.color-block-radio-grp-label(for="radio", ng-class="'priority-{{ priority }}'", ng-focus="focus='true'")
                        | &nbsp {{ priority | alertPriority }}
```

Should I use some other input type to make it happen or try to change something in this code itself?

Answer (score 1):

## Html solution

Here is how i would solve the problem:
Just change the html and css-stylesheet.
(Note,  i do not know any angularjs so i might be totaly wrong here)

```css
.pretty-radio label {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.pretty-radio input[type=radio].Urgent:checked ~ Label.Urgent::before,
.pretty-radio input[type=radio].High:checked ~ Label.High::before,
.pretty-radio input[type=radio].Medium:checked ~ Label.Medium::before,
.pretty-radio input[type=radio].Low:checked ~ Label.Low::before,
.pretty-radio input[type=radio].None:checked ~ Label.None::before {
  content: '✔';
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
.pretty-radio input[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
.pretty-radio input.Urgent ~ Label.Urgent {
  border-color: #D0231C;
  color: #D0231C;
}
.pretty-radio input.Urgent:focus ~ Label.Urgent {
  background-color: #D0231C;
  color: white;
}
.pretty-radio input.High ~ Label.High {
  border-color: #FF9700;
  color: #FF9700;
}
.pretty-radio input.High:focus ~ Label.High {
  background-color: #FF9700;
  color: white;
}
.pretty-radio input.Medium ~ Label.Medium {
  border-color: #F2C335;
  color: #F2C335;
}
.pretty-radio input.Medium:focus ~ Label.Medium {
  background-color: #F2C335;
  color: white;
}
.pretty-radio input.Low ~ Label.Low {
  border-color: #69A94B;
  color: #69A94B;
}
.pretty-radio input.Low:focus ~ Label.Low {
  background-color: #69A94B;
  color: white;
}
.pretty-radio input.None ~ Label.None {
  border-color: #888;
  color: #888;
}
.pretty-radio input.None:focus ~ Label.None {
  background-color: #888;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="pretty-radio">
  <input id="5" name="level" class="Urgent" type="radio" />
  <label for="5" class="Urgent">Urgent</label>

  <input id="4" name="level" class="High" type="radio" />
  <label for="4" class="High">High</label>

  <input id="3" name="level" class="Medium" type="radio" />
  <label for="3" class="Medium">Medium</label>

  <input id="2" name="level" class="Low" type="radio" />
  <label for="2" class="Low">Low</label>

  <input id="1" name="level" class="None" type="radio" />
  <label for="1" class="None">None</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort @Persijn. But i cannot make the labels static. It has to be dynamic. I will try to generalise the code that you have come up with